# Is there a simple service registry for Java?

Tags: java

I have an interface like `SomeProvider` and several `SomeProviderImpl`s. I now want to register all my implementations at a central place and have something like `Registry.get(SomeProvider.class, param1, param2, ...)` to query one of the implementations.

Since OSGi and OSGi DS would be like nuking a fly, I am about to roll my own simple and tiny registry, but I wanted to know if something like that already exists.

Comment: You could use the Spring framework and annotate your `SomeProviderImpl`s with the `@Component` annotation, then you could get all the implementations by looking up all beans in the Spring context that implement interface `SomeProvider`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `java.util.ServiceLoader` in java that allows simple registration and retrieval of the services.

Comment: This is the correct solution.  See also [ServiceLoader documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).  Implementations don't even need to register themselves.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this.

Comment: This works like a charm, is small and simple, and even part of the Java standard library. Just what I wanted. Thanks!